# Tomcat automatic recovery

Tags: linux, tomcat

I wonder if there is a way to detect if a Tomcat Server has been crashed on a LInux machine? How can i 
recover it (- start it) automatically?

I can do it through a cron job. But that is not what i Want!

I want to detect immediately the time that Tomcat crashed!
Is there a way?

Any help?

Antonis

Comment: I'm curious, why is a cron job not what you want?

Comment: You may have to create a program that monitors whether the Tomcat process has terminated abnormally and start it up again if it has.

Comment: A python script would do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at mysqld_safe.  It is mysql's launch script that monitors mysql and can recover from some errors and relaunch mysql again.  You might get some hints on how to do the same thing for tomcat.

A link on how the script work is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqld-safe.html).